# Does console.assert output go anywhere?

Tags: javascript, console, jxbrowser

I'm trying to test my javascript code in jxBrowser. Using `console.assert` does not generate any errors, but also does not generate any output.  I'm catching `console.log` messages fine. Is there any way to get `console.assert` messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [`console.assert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/assert) writes an error message to the console if the assertion is `false`. If the assertion is `true`, nothing happens. Please make sure that your assertion is `false`.